# C# guidelines for exception documentation

Tags: c#

The API I'm working on is becoming quite large and now I'm working on some multi-threaded stuff, so I want to make sure that I know all exceptions that can occur at any given point. I know C# does not have checked exceptions that you have to declare with each method, like Java, but I figured I would do it in the documentation for each method.

Consider the following very simple example:

```
/// <exception cref="System.DivideByZeroException">oh no, divide by zero.</exception>
int someMethod(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b; //this might throw DivideByZeroException
}

//clearly this method can never throw a DivideByZeroException
int someOtherMethod(int a)
{
    return someMethod(a, 2);
}
```

Do I add the DivideByZeroException tag to "someOtherMethod"?

Of course this is just a very simple example and the real code is more complex, but sometimes I know an exception that a sub-method throws can never occur. Not because I catch it, but because I will always pass valid arguments to it.

If I want documentation for exceptions then I have 3 options:

1) Act like that exception will never happen and don't add the tag to the documentation (because it never will, and I have unit tests to back it up).

2) Add an exception tag for an exception that I know will never happen.

3) Do a try-catch and ignore, to make sure it will never happen, so I can remove it from the list of exceptions with good conscious.

I like option 1 the most, but is there any sort of guidelines for this?

Comment: How about just adding assertion to the one you are sure that you're not going to pass invalid data ?

Comment: What if SomeMethod is virtual? How can you know which exceptions it might throw? Or if you call methods on a passed in type (interface / generic type argument)?

Comment: The example is just the most simple I could think of. I could give some concreate examples from the code, but they require too much explanation. There are no other cases like virtual or generic types. It all comes down to me calling a method that can throw an exception if the arguments are not valid, but because the arguments in question are constant and always valid, the calling method will never see the exception.

Comment: The exceptions should be documented on an API as "which exceptions can be thrown if I call this method?". Documenting exceptions which will never throw is absurd. @user18044 if you extend the API, it is your duty to document that extension.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen any kind of guidelines regarding this, but developers mostly logical people and expect to see in documentation exceptions that can occur and never see those that cannot. Just be logical, it is often much better than following guidelines (which is also important, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general rule, when you are designing an API, make sure you have XML comments for all public methods so that developer who wants to use your API knows exactly what your method do.

And for your case you should add comment for someOtherMethod that this can throw DivideByZeroException. Visual studio will not help you in identifying that some inner method can throw the exception. You have to track this manually.

Here is a code example

```
public void MethodA(object someObject, int a, int b)
{
    if (someObject == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    MethodB(a, b);
    MethodC(b, a); // Possibility of OverflowException,
}

public void MethodAA(object someObject, int a, int b)
{
    if (someObject == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    MethodB(a, b);
    MethodC(b, b); // No Possibility of OverflowException,
}

internal int MethodB(int a, int b)
{
    return a/b; // This can throw DivideByZeroException
}

public int MethodC(int a, int b)
{
    retirm a - b; // This can cause Overflow exception.
}
```

Now MethodA XML comments should have ArgumentNullException, DivideByZeroException and OverFlowException. As all cases are possible. But for MethodC you should have only OverFlowException.

But for method AA, you will never get OverFlowException. So for MethodAA you should have XML comments for ArgumentNullException, DivideByZeroException.

Comment: Why do I need to add comment for someOtherMethod that this can throw DivideByZeroException. In the example given, it can never throw DivideByZeroException. Is this the normal thing to do? The API has many layers, so the outer layers will have many exception tags if I don’t remove the exceptions for invalid arguments that I know is valid because they are constant.

Comment: You shouldn't. If you see MethodAA in answer then it doesn't throw OverFlowException so it will not write that in the comments,

Comment: If you look at the documentation of .NET code, then you clearly sees all expected exceptions. And if you browse that code you will see that most of these exceptions came from inner methods. Writing all exceptions will make sure that developer catches exact exception and do the fallback. If you don't write that it can throw a certain exception then developer will not handle it, resulting in crash,

Answer (score 0):

Considera a more general case where you'd be throwing a different exception from the one raised in the inner call (nonsensical example follows for simplicity's sake):

```
public class Foo
{
    int b;

    public int GetBar(int a)
    {
        try
        {
            return helperGetBar(a, b);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("...", e); //object has not been initialized correctly.
        } 
    }

    static int helperGetBar(int a, int b)
    {
        return a/b; //Can raise DivideByZeroExpection
    }
}
```

Why would you want to document `GetBar` as raising a `DivideByZeroException` when it is not possible at all?

You'd only document `InvalidOperationException` becuase it is the *only* exception the method can raise. If the method can't raise any exception then there is nothing to document.